# What is the fastest public SHA256^2 code for x86?

Tags: sha256

I am asking about the *double* SHA256 hashing function - the one that bitcoin uses.

Which publicly available implementation is the fastest one out there?

It can be in assembler, as long as it is for x86, also 64 bit.

Comment: I suspect, that since SHA256 has no real weaknesses, you can't do 2x SHA256 faster than twice the time of one SHA256...